# How to find the eigenfunctions of a differential operator.

Tags: operator-theory, eigenfunctions

Consider a linear differential operator $$L=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}.$$ How would one determine that the normalised eigenfunctions of $L$ are $$\phi_n(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin{(n\pi x)}?$$

Comment: which initial conditions do u have in mind?

Comment: I think y(1)=Cy(0) but I will double-check and get back to you later.

Answer (score 8):

To find its eigenfunction $f$, it is equivalent to solve 
$Lf=\lambda f$, that is, 
$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\lambda f.$$
This is an second order ODE with constant coefficient, which can be solved. After finding all the possible solutions for $f$, we can consider the normalized condition and initial conditions to find the specify $f$.

Comment: OK cool, so with boundary conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$ I obtain $f=A\cos{\lambda x}+B\sin{\lambda x}=\sqrt{2}\sin{\lambda x}$ where $A=0$ and $B=\sqrt{2}$ from the boundary conditions. But then how does one determine that $\lambda_n=n\pi$?

Comment: @ODP from normalization. If you are using 2-norm, simply integrate $f^2$ over the domain and equate that to 1.